# How to create tabs using jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, tabs, flot

I have a Flot graph  which i need to keep in one of the tabs.
Here is the Flot Graph [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/WnC9B/)

How to create tabs and place this graph in one of it using jquery mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably everything you need to know is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370015/jquery-mobile-with-flot-and-ajax-navigation).

Essentially, just use jQueryMobile pages and attach an event to the pageshow for the page with teh graph in it, and have that plot your graph.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jQueryMobile Splitview](http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/) plugin.

Or maybe jQueryMobile native [navbars](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html)?